# Azure Key Vault with Managed Service Identity on self Hosted Web App

Tags: azure, asp.net-core

Could anyone provide some instruction on how you would go about assigning a Managed Service Identity to a Remotely-hosted Web app?

My application is registered in `AAD` to enable the use of authentication. I want to remove the `appSecret` from `appsettings` and store that in the `KeyVault` and access the `KeyVault` using the `MSI`.

I have looked at the `MS docs` and followed a few guides, but have not, as of yet, managed to successfully retrieve my secret.
In the first instance, I just wanted to store a secret and get that back, and once that was working, get the client secret using the same approach.

Comment: Where are you hosting your app? Managed identity only works when you host your app in Azure.

Comment: Excellent (kind of)!! This is the definitive answer I was looking for. I had been told that it would work when self-hosted but did think this was true. Thanks for the confirmation.

Answer (score 0):

Managed identity only works when you host your app in Azure.

This is because it works as a local endpoint inside the Azure instances.